# LINQ How to get difference

Tags: asp.net, linq

I have two lists

```
var items = new[] { "one", "two", "three" };
var items2 = new[] { "one" };
```

I would like to compare two list and get the items that are not available in items2.Basically need the following output

```
two three
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
items.Except(items2).ToList().ForEach(x=>Console.Write(x));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
items.Except(items2);
```

will give you your expected result.